# Reading ListBox's SelectedItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox and a TextBox on my form. Upon ListBox's `SelectedIndexChanged` event I want to show what is currently selected in the ListBox. The ListBox is bound to a DataSource, the type of which is unknown at design-time. I do know the value of `DisplayMember` (which the ListBox apparently uses to display each item's text). How do I get the selected item's Text? Does it need Reflection, or is there a direct way?

Comment: What problem do you have using SelectedItem?

Comment: @Steve: It could return `System.Data.DataRowView` if bound to a `DataView` (or anything at all depending on what it is bound to); not the string that the selected item is showing in the ListBox.

Comment: But if you set the DisplayMember then you should get the value of that column. Or not?

Comment: @Steve: I could. The probelm is that I don't know beforehand the type of its data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the selected item is a datarowview, then you can use the displaymember to get the displayValue with:

```
System.Data.DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem;
string displayValue = Convert.ToString(drv[listBox1.DisplayMember]);
```

There's also the getItemText function:

```
listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Read my comments above. It isn't that simple.